# "Multiple definition" error when statically linking

Tags: c++, function, linker, linker-errors, multiple-definition-error

I'm trying to compile a link together these simple example programs:

main.cpp:

```
#include "server.hpp"

int main()
{

}
```

server.hpp:

```
#ifndef SERVER_HPP
#define SERVER_HPP

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class Server
{
    boost::asio::io_context context;

    void listen();
};

#endif
```

server.cpp:

```
#include "server.hpp"

void Server::listen()
{
    static boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor {
        context,
        {boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 1000}
    };
}
```

I'm compiling all this with gcc 13.1:

> g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -std=c++23 .\main.cpp .\server.cpp -lws2_32

However, for some reason I cannot understand, I get this linker error:

> D:/Programmi/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Programmi/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../lib\libstdc++.a(tinfo.o):(.text$*ZNKSt9type_infoeqERKS*+0x0): multiple definition of `std::type_info::operator==(std::type_info const&) const'; C:\Users\jayok\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4dUKMC.o:server.cpp:(.text$*ZNKSt9type_infoeqERKS*[*ZNKSt9type_infoeqERKS*]+0x0): first defined here
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

If I make the body of the "listen" function empty, or if I make the linking not-static by omitting those arguments, however, this error no longer appears, and the compilation is successful.

Comment: FYI, tested with MSVC and boost 1.82.0, no issue with or without static with the code samples you provided. It builds well.

Comment: So, could it be a compiler bug? How do I signal it to the developer?

Comment: gcc12.2 gives the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, could it be a compiler bug?

Indeed, this seems to be a GCC — or rather `libstdc++` — related issue.

The reason there's nothing much to find about it is that it [only seems to occur](https://github.com/skeeto/w64devkit/issues/86) with `c++23` *and* static linking, so probably not very many of us have hit it.

> How do I signal it to the developer?

From the [libstdc++ docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bugs.html):

> #### Implementation Bugs
>
> Information on known bugs, details on efforts to fix them, and fixed
> bugs are all available as part of the [GCC bug tracking system](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/), under
> the component “libstdc++”.

***[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=110572), it's been reported** now, actually. (Couldn't find it initially, but came back with the update.)*

##### Workaround:

If you can do without RTTI, then  compiling with `-fno-rtti` can save your build.